# Android Studio MediaStore Storage can't access the folder

Tags: android, kotlin

When trying to download and save a file, it throws an error

```
Primary directory file not allowed for content://media/external/downloads;
allowed directories are [Download]
```

How can I fix it, maybe there is no permission?

```
val multipartBuilder = MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM)

                    multipartBuilder.addFormDataPart("oid", orderId)

                    val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                        .connectTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .writeTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .readTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .build()

                    val request = Request.Builder()
                        .url(Api.API_URL + "order/shopOrderPrintAgreement")
                        .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer ${Api.token}")
                        .post(multipartBuilder.build())
                        .build()

                    val response = client.newCall(request).execute()

                    /**
                     *TODO починить для android 10
                     */
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                        val resolver = context!!.contentResolver
                        val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
                            put(MediaStore.DownloadColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "agreement_$orderId")
                            put(MediaStore.DownloadColumns.MIME_TYPE, "application/pdf")
                            put(MediaStore.DownloadColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, "file/Peshkariki")
                        }
                        // MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
                        val uri = resolver.insert(
                            MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                            contentValues
                        )

                        if (uri != null) {
                            try {
                                resolver.openOutputStream(uri).use {
                                    it?.let {
                                        val sink = it.sink().buffer()
                                        sink.writeAll(response.body()!!.source())
                                        sink.close()
                                    }
                                }

                                mainActivity.runOnUiThread {
                                    dialog?.dismiss()
                                    try {
                                        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                                        intent.setDataAndType(
                                            uri, "application/pdf"
                                        )
                                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY)
                                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)

                                        if (isActivityForIntentAvailable(intent)) {
                                            startActivity(intent)
                                        } else {
                                            val webIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                                            webIntent.setDataAndType(
                                                uri, "text/html"
                                            )
                                            webIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY)
                                            webIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
                                            startActivity(webIntent)
                                        }
                                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                                        e.printStackTrace()
                                        Toast.makeText(
                                            mainActivity,
                                            "Не удалось открыть файл",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                                        ).show()
                                    }
                                }
                            } catch (e: Exception) {
                                Crashlytics.logException(e)
                            }
                        } else {
                            log("OrderClientFragment error with uri == null")
                            Crashlytics.log("OrderClientFragment error with uri == null ")
                        }
```

List of all permissions that I have declared in manifest and use in my project

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Traceback

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Primary directory file not allowed for content://media/external/downloads; allowed directories are [Download]
        at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.ensureFileColumns(MediaProvider.java:2117)
        at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.ensureUniqueFileColumns(MediaProvider.java:1928)
        at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.insertFile(MediaProvider.java:2495)
        at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.insertInternal(MediaProvider.java:3254)
        at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.insert(MediaProvider.java:2903)
        at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.insert(ContentProvider.java:309)
        at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:154)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1021)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:994)
2020-05-01 19:05:44.698 7774-7992/com.app.peshkariki E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-20
    Process: com.app.peshkariki, PID: 7774
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Primary directory file not allowed for content://media/external/downloads; allowed directories are [Download]
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:170)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:140)
        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:481)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1828)
        at com.app.peshkariki.i.i$n0.run(OrderClientFragment.kt:778)
```

778 line, this is

```
val uri = resolver.insert(
                            MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                            contentValues
                        )
```

It seems that all the necessary permissions are used in the project, so I don't even know which way to look to solve this problem

Comment: can you try this =>MediaStore.DownloadColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, "Download/Peshkariki"

Comment: @KasimOzdemir thanks, very much

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use:

```
put(MediaStore.DownloadColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, "Download/Peshkariki")
```

instead of

```
put(MediaStore.DownloadColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, "file/Peshkariki")
```

> Primary directory **file** not allowed

Comment: after 3 hours of straggling, I found it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            final ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
            final ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "image_name"); //It automatically adds .jpg
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
            final Uri uri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);

            if(uri == null){
                throw new IOException("Failed to create new MediaStore record.");
            }

            final OutputStream stream = resolver.openOutputStream(uri);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            Log.d(TAG, "moveTemplateToDownloads: Successfully moved to downloads.");
        }
```

Here is the full working Java solution for saving bitmap to the Download directory using scoped storage.

It didn't work for me at first because I was using `MediaStore.MediaColumns.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`, but after switching it to `MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` it was successfully saving to Download directory.

Note:

After running this block of code, you need to pulldown refresh the `Files` app for the image to appear.